# GKE cluster creation failed in health check

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, cluster-computing

I'm tried to create a GKE standard cluster. I'm continuously facing creation failed after it reaches 83% cluster creation. It failed in Health check stage. Is there any solution to solve this problem?

I'm expecting better solution to solve this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you have to share the command and log , error information then only other are able to help. Check is enough quota available for K85 cluster creation

Comment: All cluster resources were brought up, but: only 0 nodes out of 3 have registered; cluster may be unhealthy.

this is the error i'm getting now.

Comment: not able to see the error